# Gradle - custom task which runs multiple tasks in sequence

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I need to create gradle task which will be executing another 4 tasks (from plugins) in sequence - one by one

```
task dailyTask (type: GradleBuild, dependsOn: ['lint', 'ktfmtCheck', 'testDebugUnitTest', 'koverVerify' ]) {
    ktfmtCheck.mustRunAfter('lint')
    testDebugUnitTest.mustRunAfter('ktfmtCheck')
    koverVerify.mustRunAfter('testDebugUnitTest')
}
```

I tried in this way, but i don't find it as valid solution, additionally i've got an error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'testDebugUnitTest' for task ':xxxxxxx-app:dailyTask' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle now recommends a different syntax for declaring tasks:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

```
def copy = tasks.register('copy', Copy) {
    from(file('srcDir'))
    into(buildDir)
}
```

For setting up `mustRunAfter()`, you need to do this out in the main global scope of the file, not in the task configuration closure of an unrelated task. This can also be done in the configuration closure of each of those specific tasks.